# Comparing two data sets for matches and nonmatches

Tags: excel

I have data in two different sheets. Sheet1.A will contain an alphanumeric entry "ABC123" and Sheet2.A will contain a similar entry "ABC123 some text" or "some text ABC123"

Additionally Sheet1 will always have less entries than Sheet2, therefore there will be nonmatches.

In Sheet3 I want to be able to display all the entries for Sheet1.A with its corresponding match from Sheet2.A and then for all non matches, I would like them to be displayed at the bottom of the list.

Example of ideal output:

```
Sheet3.A  Sheet3.B
ABC123    ABC123
ABC222    ABC222
ABC333    ABC333
          ABC444
          ABC555
          ABC666
```

Currently I am using an index match (with a LEFT function) formula for Sheet3.B but does not produce an ideal output:

```
Sheet3.A  Sheet3.B
ABC123    ABC123
ABC222    ABC222
ABC333    ABC333
          ABC444
          ABC444
          ABC444
```

Also because I am using a LEFT function and the data in Sheet2.A may not be arranged similar to Sheet1.A, some entries are not being found, thus producing #N/A

I would also like to add that Sheet2.A may contain more than 256 characters which is causing problems for the index match function. This issue is not a top priority but if it can be resolved as well, that would be great.

***Edit:***

Question and Accepted answer now properly reflect one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use the `.Find` method, searching for partial matches.

```
Sub FindPartialString()

Dim wsList As Worksheet
Dim wsSearch As Worksheet
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rngList As Range
Dim rngMatch As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim arrNonMatches() As Variant
Dim nonMatchCount As Long


Set wsList = Sheets(1) '## Modify as needed
Set wsSearch = Sheets(2) '## Modify as needed
Set wsOutput = Sheets(3) '## Modify as needed
Set rngList = wsList.Range("A2:A5") '## Modify as needed

For Each cl In rngList
    Set rngMatch = Nothing 'clear the container before each query
    'look for a partial match:
    Set rngMatch = wsSearch.Cells.Find(What:=cl.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    'Store the matches and non matches in separate arrays:
    If Not rngMatch Is Nothing Then
        lastRow = 1 + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsOutput.Range("A:A"))
        'put the searched value in column A:
        wsOutput.Cells(lastRow, 1) = cl.Value
        'Put the found value in column B:
        wsOutput.Cells(lastRow, 2) = rngMatch.Value
    Else:
        'store non-matches in an array
        ReDim Preserve arrNonMatches(nonMatchCount)
        arrNonMatches(nonMatchCount) = cl.Value
        nonMatchCount = nonMatchCount + 1
    End If
Next

'Print out the non-matches
lastRow = lastRow + 1
wsOutput.Cells(lastRow, 1).Resize(UBound(arrNonMatches) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrNonMatches)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks David - your solution is very close to reaching my desired output. However I should clarify something - an item in wsList may not exist in wsSearch. Because of this, the current subroutine is outputting wsList nonmatches in wsOutput column A and a blank for wsOutput column B.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? `then for all non matches, I would like them to be displayed at the bottom of the list.`  What would you want in column B? There is no match, so I put the non-matches at the bottom of column A, as I understood the question.

Comment: I had accidently submitted my comment without a complete response. I have edited my original question to reflect this change in desired output - please forgive the lack of clarity within the original question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you've changed in the request. As I understand it, you want the searched for values in column A of the Output sheet, if there is a match. You also want the found values (match) put in column B. Isn't that what my code is doing?

Comment: To further clarify, let's say Sheet1.A has 200 items. Sheet2.A has 300 items. Currently, the subroutine will run until row 200 (displaying all Sheet1.A items) but this means that 100 items from Sheet2.A are not accounted for.

Comment: If you know anything about VBA, you should be able to manipulate the above code by adding another loop to check both ways. I've given you 99% of the code base to perform the operations you need. If you are not familiar with VBA, then you're in the wrong place. I'll gladly hire my services to do your job, but otherwise, I'm here to assist people with writing code, not to do their jobs gratis.  Cheers.

Comment: David - the solution in which you submitted had solved 100% the original problem posed and with great efficiency. As you have eluded to, StackOverflow is to assist and not to do one's job for them. I have modified your answer to my needs and appreciate the help you have given.